# Building a vector from components contained in another vector type

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, boost

I have a code that looks something like this:

```
struct First
{
    int f1;
    int f2;
};

struct Second
{
    First s1;
    int s2;
};

std::vector < Second > secondVec;

Second sec;
sec.s1 = First(); 

secondVec.push_back(sec);
secondVec.push_back(sec);

std::vector < First > firstVec;
firstVec.reserve(secondVec.size());

for (std::vector < Second >::iterator secIter = secondVec.begin(); 
         secIter != = secondVec.end();
         ++secIter)
{
    firstVec.push_back(secIter->s1);
}
```

I'd like to replace this ugly `for` loop with a simple stl function that could perhaps perform the equivalent process.  I was thinking that maybe `std::transform` could help me here, but I'm unsure as to how this could be written.

I'd also be interested if *boost* has anything to offer here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have TR1 or Boost available, you could try this:

```
std::transform(secondVec.begin(),
               secondVec.end(),
               std::back_inserter(firstVec),
               std::tr1::bind(&Second::s1, _1));
```

Answer (score 5):

Define functor that will transform Second to First:

```
struct StoF { First operator()( const Second& s ) const { return s.s1; } };
```

Then use it in the following way:

```
transform( secondVec.begin(), secondVec.end(), back_inserter(firstVec), StoF() );
```

If your source vector contains a lot of elements you should consider resizing destination vector to make it work faster, as in @Goz answer:

```
firstVec.resize( secondVec.size() );
transform( secondVec.begin(), secondVec.end(), firstVec.begin(), StoF() );
```

Answer (score 3):

Its not particularly difficult ... I tried this and it worked no problems.

```
struct First
{
    int f1;
    int f2;
};

struct Second
{
    First s1;
    int s2;
};

First Replace( Second& sec )
{
    return sec.s1;
}
```

and then used the following code to copy it

```
std::vector < Second > secondVec;

Second sec;
sec.s1.f1 = 0; 
sec.s1.f2 = 1; 
secondVec.push_back(sec);

sec.s1.f1 = 2; 
sec.s1.f2 = 3; 
secondVec.push_back(sec);

std::vector < First > firstVec;
firstVec.resize( secondVec.size() );
std::transform( secondVec.begin(), secondVec.end(), firstVec.begin(), Replace );
```

Comment: Why not to return `sec.s1` in `Replace` function?

Comment: You could do that, yeah.  I saw someone else's response and thought "Thats a good point".  Will edit my post now.

Comment: Although for some reason, I prefer using a back_inserter (while reserving before), your method of proceeding is as good if not a tad more efficient.

Comment: It was one of those hammer out a little block of code to solve a problem without thinking it through entirely :)

Answer (score 2):

You were right with your intuition. Although since you are using an empty vector, you should use a *back inserter* for your output iterator.

It should look like something of the like :

```
std::transform(secondVec.being(), secondVec.end(), back_inserter(firstVec), yourFunctor)
```

And yourFunctor looking like this :

```
void youFunctor(First param)
{
  return param.s1;
}
```

Edit : Boost could help you with lambda function so you wouldn't have to create a separate functor for this task. You should also note that lambda function function are part of the TR1 and will be integrated to the C++ standard library.

Edit : Here is what Meredith was talking about with mem_fun (or member function adaptor).

```
 struct Second
{
    First s1;
    int s2;
    First getS1() const {return s1;};
};
```

And then the transform would look like this :

```
std::transform(secondVec.being(), 
               secondVec.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(firstVec), 
               std::mem_fun(&Second::getS1))
```

Comment: You could also add a getter for `s1` to the `Second` class, and then use `std::mem_fun` to adapt the getter into a functor, rather than having to write an explicit functor. I prefer this because it keeps my code more organized, but some people seem to be scared of `<functional>`.

Comment: Meredith, If you have time, I'd very much appreciate an example piece of code to illustrate this method - I'm intrigued!

Comment: This approach would be better if you were using a class though as it would allow you to encapsulate your data.